# Error after renaming SSRS linked report names

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, microsoft-reporting

I have changed the SSRS report names in my reporting server projects. I have four reports and four linked reports in this projects. The linked reports are being called by an action setup on a column value where the parameters are being passed to the linked reports. After renaming all the report names I have made similar changes in the Action property in order direct the parameters to the changed report name. I have also saved the changes and re-built the project and have not got any errors. All the four main reports are working fine but the linked reports are trowing the following error while running the reports using preview options in MS Visual Studio 2010

An error occurred during local report processing. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have deployed this to my local report server and on browser I getting the following error

The item '/Unit Reports/OLDREPORTNAME' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)

Here you can see that it is still trying to locate it to the old report name not the new changed one.

I have clean, built and deployed the project several times but still getting these errors

Please let me know if I need to make changes in any other files to avoid this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that when I implement the Action property on the report field, it automatically set-up the same Action property of that text box where the field was defined.

I have found that the text box Action property was still pointing to the old report. I have changed text box Action property to point it to the new report and now my linked reports are working absolutely fine.

Thanks

Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

Within the .rdl search for "OLDREPORTNAME" and replace with "NEWREPORTNAME"...

Take a backup first :-)

Comment: Thanks Jim, i have tried it but did not work. I have found why is it happening though and a way to resolve this issue which I would explain in the answer of this question.

Comment: If you had done what I suggested it would have worked ? The action box property would be pointing to the new report ?!

Comment: Jim, I did try that and changed the names and saved it. But when you run the report the .rdl file was still overwriting the old report name.

Comment: How can it?!! If the old report name doesn't exist in your rdl how is it possible that it can revert to the old report name.

Unless you have inadvertently created artificial un-intelligence that is!

Comment: Hi Jim, it seems like the text box action property was automatically set as do not remember setting it up separately in the report. I now need to check if setting up a place holder Action property will automatically set up the text box property or not. If yes then I would need to delete the placeholder action property as there is no point keeping this property on 2 different paces on a report.